# node.js with PostgreSQL and socket.io Error: Socket is not writable

Tags: postgresql, node.js, websocket, socket.io, node-postgres

I've been playing around with socket.io and it seems to have been working nicely. Lately though, I installed postgreSQL to insert rows to the database everytime an event happens (and the event happens 2 or 3 times per second!)... Here's a snippet:

```
pg.connect(conString, function(err, dbClient) {
  io.sockets.on("connection", function(client) {
    client.on("clientSendingPlayerData", function(playerData) {
      dbClient.query("insert into actions values (1)", function() {
        console.log("INSERTED ROW");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

We get the error:

```
net.js:391
    throw new Error('Socket is not writable');
          ^
Error: Socket is not writable
    at Socket._writeOut (net.js:391:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:377:17)
    at [object Object].query (/homes/jjl310/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:109:15)
    at [object Object].submit (/homes/jjl310/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:99:16)
    at [object Object]._pulseQueryQueue (/homes/jjl310/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:166:24)
    at [object Object].query (/homes/jjl310/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:193:8)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/homes/jjl310/tradersgame/server.js:182:16)
    at Socket.$emit (events.js:64:17)
    at SocketNamespace.handlePacket (/homes/jjl310/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:335:22)
    at Manager.onClientMessage (/homes/jjl310/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:469:38)
```

Any ideas as to what's causing the problem and how it could be fixed?

I'm using the following library for postrgreSQL
https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

Answer (score 2):

`pg.connect()` gets a connection from the pool, `dbClient` is an active connection. Long running connections can timeout, error or be dropped for inactivity. You want to move `pg.connect()` in to the `clientSendingPlayerData` callback. That way a db connetion gets pull from the pool only when needed and is returned to the pool when finished.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go.. Question is, is it OK to connect to the database every time an event happens? Remember the event is fired quite frequently...

Comment: `pg.connect()` is sets up and uses a client pool. If you need to do multiple queries as a group/transaction then doing that with a the same client is fine. Just don't hold clients around for use later as it will empty your pool out and you wont gain much if anything. `var client = new pg.Client(...)` setups up non-pooled connection, which I think is what `pg.connect()` is being confused with.